# Mutable vectors in struct

Tags: graph, rust

I'm trying to get a graph clustering algorithm to work in Rust. Part of the code is a `WeightedGraph` data structure with an adjacency list representation. The core would be represented like this (shown in Python to make it clear what I'm trying to do):

```py
class Edge(object):
    def __init__(self, target, weight):
        self.target = target
        self.weight = weight

class WeightedGraph(object):
    def __init__(self, initial_size):
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for i in range(initial_size)]
        self.size = initial_size
        self.edge_count = 0

    def add_edge(self, source, target, weight):
        self.adjacency_list[source].append(Edge(target, weight))
        self.edge_count += 1
```

So, the adjacency list holds an array of `n` arrays: one array for each node in the graph. The inner array holds the neighbors of that node, represented as `Edge` (the `target` node number and the double `weight`).

My attempt to translate the whole thing to Rust looks like this:

```
struct Edge {
    target: uint,
    weight: f64
}

struct WeightedGraph {
    adjacency_list: ~Vec<~Vec<Edge>>,
    size: uint,
    edge_count: int
}

impl WeightedGraph {
    fn new(num_nodes: uint) -> WeightedGraph {
        let mut adjacency_list: ~Vec<~Vec<Edge>> = box Vec::from_fn(num_nodes, |idx| box Vec::new());

        WeightedGraph {
            adjacency_list: adjacency_list,
            size: num_nodes,
            edge_count: 0
        }
    }

    fn add_edge(mut self, source: uint, target: uint, weight: f64) {
        self.adjacency_list.get(source).push(Edge { target: target, weight: weight });
        self.edge_count += 1;
    }
}
```

But rustc gives me this error:

```
weightedgraph.rs:24:9: 24:40 error: cannot borrow immutable dereference of `~`-pointer as mutable
weightedgraph.rs:24         self.adjacency_list.get(source).push(Edge { target: target, weight: weight });
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, 2 main questions:

**1. How can I get the `add_edge` method to work?**

I'm thinking that WeightedGraph is supposed to own all its inner data (please correct me if I'm wrong). But why can `add_edge` not modify the graph's own data?

**2. Is `~Vec<~Vec<Edge>>` the correct way to represent a variable-sized array/list that holds a dynamic list in each element?**

The tutorial also mentions `~[int]` as vector syntax, so should it be: `~[~[Edge]]` instead? Or what is the difference between `Vec<Edge>` and `~[Edge]`? And if I'm supposed to use `~[~[Edge]]`, how would I construct/initialize the inner lists then? (currently, I tried to use `Vec::from_fn`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `WeightedGraph` does own all its inner data, but even if you own something you have to opt into mutating it. `get` gives you a `&` pointer, to mutate you need a `&mut` pointer. `Vec::get_mut` will give you that: `self.adjacency_list.get_mut(source).push(...)`.

Regarding `~Vec<Edge>` and `~[Edge]`: It used to be (until very recently) that `~[T]` denoted a growable vector of `T`, unlike every other type that's written `~...` This special case was removed and `~[T]` is now just a unique pointer to a `T`-slice, i.e. an owning pointer to a bunch of `T`s in memory without any growth capability. `Vec<T>` is now the growable vector type.

Note that it's `Vec<T>`, **not** `~Vec<T>`; the `~` used to be part of the vector syntax but here it's just an ordinary unique pointer and represents completely unnecessary indirection and allocation. You want `adjacency_list: Vec<Vec<Edge>>`. A `Vec<T>` is a fully fledged concrete type (a triple `data, length, capacity` if that means anything to you), it encapsulates the memory allocation and indirection and you can use it as a value. You gain nothing by `box`ing it, and lose clarity as well as performance.

You have another (minor) issue: `fn add_edge(mut self, ...)`, like `fn add_edge(self, ...)`, means "take `self` by value". Since the `adjacency_list` member is a linear type (it can be `drop`ped, it is moved instead of copied implicitly), your `WeightedGraph` is also a linear type. The following code will fail because the first `add_edge` call *consumed* the graph.

```
let g = WeightedGraph::new(2);
g.add_edge(1, 0, 2); // moving out of g
g.add_edge(0, 1, 3); // error: use of g after move
```

You want `&mut self`: Allow mutation of `self` but don't take ownership of it/don't move it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! About the `~Vec<T>` part: I am still a little bit confused because the tutorial contains linked list code (in section 9.1 Boxes) that uses `Cons(u32, ~List)`. That made me think that references to structs/enums/types within another struct need a `~`. So, is the `~` for the linked list only because of the recursive aspect? And what would be 'non-concrete' type which cannot be used directly as a value?

Comment: "This special case was removed and ~[T] is now just a unique pointer to a T-slice" just a point of pedantry: the change in representation hasn't happened yet, so it's still represented as a growable vector, but all the growing methods (`.push` etc.) have been removed. Hopefully the representation will be changed soon.

Comment: @MartinS., yes, `~` is present there only to allow recursion. [This](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/guide-pointers.html) tutorial explains pointers in detail. "Non-concrete" types which cannot be used directly as a value currently are `[T]` and `T` where `T` is a trait. That is, you cannot use `[T]` and trait objects without pointers, because their size is unknown. This is also explained in tutorials.

Comment: @dbaupp I am aware that the DST transition is not complete yet. But IMHO it's so far along and agreed-upon that (1) the new mental model matches at least the API and (2) describing the post-DST status as status quo is only a small temporary lie that aids understanding.

Answer (score 2):

1. `get` only returns immutable references, you have to use `get_mut` if you want to modify the data
2. You only need `Vec<Vec<Edge>>`, Vec is the right thing to use, `~[]` was for that purpose in the past but now means something else (or will, not sure if that is changed already)

You also have to change the signature of `add_edge` to take `&mut self` because now you are moving the ownership of `self` to `add_edge` and that is not what you want